# Style first 3 posts different to other posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I've been searching around and cannot find the right solution. I want to have the first three posts on a blog with a different markup to the rest of the posts.

I'm using Bootstrap so want to apply different divs to the first 3 posts than the rest.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This may help you get going in the right direction as well: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-different-formatting-to-just-the-first-post-on-the-first-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's within the `while` (or `foreach`, however you have it setup) statement you could use a standard iterator, i.e.

```
$i = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if($i < 4){
        // First 3
    }else{
        // The rest
    }
$i++;
endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply style them differently I believe you are looking for the [CSS `:nth-child` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

It allows for you to select specific children of a parent element by there order. In your case try the following:

```
.some-class:nth-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Unfortunately this will not work in any of the old Microsoft Internet Explorers (ones older than IE9)

Comment: I think he wants to change the HTML markup as well, not just the CSS.

Comment: @AndyWarren yeah I think you are right, I think my answer is still relevant for anybody who comes here based on the title though

Comment: Agreed.  The question title is a bit misleading, and your answer is very relevant based on the title.

Comment: Although nth child doesn't work in <= IE 8. Which saddens me but is an important consideration, as that's on the borderline for what a lot of people support. So it depends how critical the styling is to the experience. If it's decorational then it'd likely fall in to the 'nice to have', but if it communicates anything important using PHP to apply a different class (for example) would be a better approach than relying on CSS - so I'd personally still rather use an iterator in this case, as the option is there.

Comment: Sorry I do mean change the markup of the post rather than just style it, my bad :) Wasn't sure how else to word it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the final markup I went for using Nathan's solution above, just incase it helps the php-challenged like myself in the future:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): $counter = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); $counter++; ?>

    <?php if($counter <= 3): ?>
    <article class="col-md-4 main-post">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/310x220" />
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p class="date">Date posted: <?php the_date(); ?>
```

```
    <?php else: ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <article class="col-md-4 sub-post">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" /></a>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    </article>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```